# Foreman start only has one line for Django and heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I install the heroku toolbelt from the website and use pip to install django toolbelt on both mac and ubuntu vm copy.

Both of them only return one line when using foreman start:

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hero.wsgi
```

foreman start:

```
23:44:46 web.1  | started with pid 4382
```

Ctrl+C and I got:

```
23:47:36 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
23:47:36 web.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
```

I have read about the https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Missing-Output
and did:

script.py:

```
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
```

and run it with python -u script.py

What am I doing wrong? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think anything is wrong? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I thought there would be a link like http://127.0.0.1:5000/ for you to test run. Am I wrong?

Comment: But does it work when you go to that URL?

Comment: Locally if you wrote down the correct configuration for postgres_psycopg2, it works nicely. However, heroku uses a different configuration with DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://....). So I was wondering if foreman start is the one that helps you run your server locally with heroku db settings.

Comment: I mean not for 127.0.0.1:5000 because it doesn't exist.  If you use python manage.py runserver, it works if you properly configure your local postgresql db.